# The problem is that the user profile change form is always valid in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have two different forms of a model in a template
I change the user's photo with one form and edit the user's text profile with another form
The model (profile) is a one-to-one relationship with the main Django user
But I have a problem with the user photo change form
When clicking on the user profile edit form which is the profile model (for text changes)
The photo change form is also called and is always valid
My forms are from the Django form model
Definitely the main problem is the image change form, but I do not know which part of the code has a problem. I send the values ​​to the server with Ajax.
Below I will display the codes and output to convey the concept easier

**If you do not understand my problem, I can explain more to you, just give me your email address so that I can contact you. Thank you.**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhWEr.png)

**View**

```
def edit_user_view(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    c_default_user_edit_form = default_user_edit_form(
        request.POST or None,
        initial=vars(user),
        instance=user
    )
    c_user_image_editing_form = user_image_editing_form(
        request.POST or None,
        request.FILES or None,
        instance=user.profile
    )
    c_user_information_editing_form = user_information_editing_form(
        request.POST or None,
        initial=vars(user.profile),
        instance=user.profile,
    )
    if c_default_user_edit_form.is_valid():
        print("default user")
        c_default_user_edit_form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'s': 's'})
    if c_user_information_editing_form.is_valid():
        c_user_information_editing_form.save()

    if c_user_image_editing_form.is_valid():
        print("image user")
        user.profile.save()
        return JsonResponse({'src': user.profile.user_profile.url})

    context = {
        'default_user_edit_form': c_default_user_edit_form,
        'user_image_editing_form': c_user_image_editing_form,
        'user_information_editing_form': c_user_information_editing_form,
        'editing_user': user,
    }
    return render(request, 'AdminPanel/Users/user-edit.html', context)
```

**Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    gender_selection_choices = [
        ('MS', 'زن'),
        ('MR', 'مرد'),
        ('TG', 'دیگر'),
    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    user_profile = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="پروفایل",
        upload_to=RenameUserPhoto,
        validators=[ImageSizaValidators],
        default='images/User/UserProfile/icon-avatar-default.png',
        blank=True
    )
    gender_selection = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='انتخاب جنسیت',
        max_length=2,
        blank=True,
        default="NS",
        choices=gender_selection_choices,
    )
    postal_code = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='کد پستی',
        max_length=20,
        validators=[postal_code_validator],
        blank=True,
        help_text='کد پستی 10 رقمی میتواند شامل خط تیره (-) یا نباشد',
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        verbose_name='شماره تماس',
        help_text='شماره تماس باید 11 رقمی باشد و میتواند شامل صفر در ابتدای شماره نباشد',
        blank=True,
        validators=[phone_number_validator],
    )
    location_first = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="آدرس (1)"
    )
    NumberOfEmailsSentActivationLink = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        default=0,
        verbose_name="تعداد ایمیل ارسالی فعالسازی حساب کاربری"
    )
    NumberOfEmailsSentToTheUser = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        default=0,
        verbose_name="تعداد ایمیل های ارسال شده برای کاربر"
    )

    objects = CustomModelManagerProfile()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('AdminSite__Ak:edit_user_view', kwargs={
            'pk': self.user.pk
        })
```

**Form**

```
class user_information_editing_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'phone_number',
            'postal_code',
            'location_first',
            'gender_selection',

        )
        widgets = {
            'phone_number': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'تلفن همراه را وارد نمایید...',
                }),
            'postal_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'کد پستی را وارد نمایید...'
            }),
            'location_first': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'rows': 1,
                'style': 'resize:none;height:2.7125rem',
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'آدرس خود را وارد نمایید...'
            }),
            'gender_selection': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        }


class user_image_editing_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user_profile',)
        widgets = {
            'user_profile': forms.FileInput()
        }
```

**Ajax**

```
// Change User Photo
$('button.user-photo-change-btn').click(function () {
    const image_input = $('input[name="user_profile"]').click()
    let formData = new FormData();
    image_input.change(function () {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('user_profile', $('form#form-change-photo input[name="user_profile"]').prop('files')[0])
        formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $('form#form-change-photo input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val())
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: location.href,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (Data) {
                $('img.users-avatar-shadow').attr('src', Data.src)
            }
        });
    })
})

//Account change information form
$('form#account_change_information_form button[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.href,
        data: $('form#account_change_information_form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        cache:false,
        success: function () {

        }
    })
})
```

**Html**

```
{% extends 'AdminPanel/__Main__/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<!--Title-->
{% block title_edit_user %}
    ویرایش کاربر
{% endblock %}


<!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->
{% block vendor_css_edit_user %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/css-rtl/plugins/forms/validation/form-validation.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/vendors/css/forms/select/select2.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/vendors/css/pickers/pickadate/pickadate.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
<!-- END: Vendor CSS-->


<!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
{% block page_css_edit_user %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/css-rtl/pages/app-user.min.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
<!-- END: Page CSS-->


<!-- BEGIN: Content-->
{% block edit_user %}
    <div class="app-content content">
        <div class="content-overlay"></div>
        <div class="header-navbar-shadow"></div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-header row">
            </div>
            <div class="content-body"><!-- users edit start -->
                <section class="users-edit">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center active" id="account-tab"
                                           data-toggle="tab" href="#account"
                                           aria-controls="account" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
                                            <i class="feather icon-user mr-25"></i><span
                                                class="d-none d-sm-block">حساب</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" id="information-tab"
                                           data-toggle="tab" href="#information"
                                           aria-controls="information" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
                                            <i class="feather icon-info mr-25"></i><span class="d-none d-sm-block">اطلاعات</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="account" aria-labelledby="account-tab"
                                         role="tabpanel">
                                        <!-- users edit media object start -->
                                        <div class="media mb-2">
                                            <a class="mr-2 my-25" href="#">
                                                <img src="{{ editing_user.profile.user_profile.url }}" alt="users avatar"
                                                     class="users-avatar-shadow rounded" height="90" width="90">
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="media-body mt-50">
                                                <h4 class="media-heading">{{ user.get_full_name }}</h4>
                                                <div class="col-12 d-flex mt-1 px-0">
                                                    <form action="" method="post" id="form-change-photo"
                                                          class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                                        {{ user_image_editing_form.user_profile }}
                                                        <button type="button"
                                                                class="btn btn-primary d-none d-sm-block mr-75 user-photo-change-btn">
                                                            تغییر دادن
                                                        </button>

                                                        <button type="button"
                                                                class="btn btn-outline-danger d-none d-sm-block user-photo-delete-btn">
                                                            پاک کردن
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- users edit media object ends -->
                                        <!-- users edit account form start -->
                                        <form novalidate method="post" id="form_default_user">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label>پست الکترونیک</label>
                                                            {{ default_user_edit_form.username }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label>نام</label>
                                                            {{ default_user_edit_form.first_name }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label>نام خانوادگی</label>
                                                            {{ default_user_edit_form.last_name }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {# User Permission #}
                                                <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                                                    <div class="table-responsive border rounded px-1 ">
                                                        <h6 class="border-bottom py-1 mx-1 mb-0 font-medium-2"><i
                                                                class="feather icon-lock mr-50 "></i>وضعیت حساب کاربری
                                                        </h6>
                                                        <table class="table table-borderless">
                                                            <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th>دسترسی های کاربر</th>
                                                                <th>فعال / غیرفعال</th>
                                                                <th>کاربر ویژه</th>
                                                                <th>کارمند</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>کاربران</td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                                        {{ default_user_edit_form.is_active }}
                                                                        <label class="custom-control-label"
                                                                               for="user-active"></label>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                                        {{ default_user_edit_form.is_superuser }}
                                                                        <label class="custom-control-label"
                                                                               for="user-superuser"></label>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                                        {{ default_user_edit_form.is_staff }}
                                                                        <label class="custom-control-label"
                                                                               for="user-personnel"></label>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-end mt-1">
                                                    <button type="button"
                                                            class="btn btn-primary glow mb-1 mb-sm-0 mr-0 mr-sm-1"
                                                            id="btn-apply-default-user-changes">
                                                        ذخیره تغییرات
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning">تنظیم مجدد
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        <!-- users edit account form ends -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="information" aria-labelledby="information-tab"
                                         role="tabpanel">
                                        <!-- users edit Info form start -->
                                        <form method="post" novalidate id="account_change_information_form">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="row mt-1">
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <h5 class="mb-1"><i class="feather icon-user mr-25"></i>اطلاعات شخصی
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label for="">تلفن همراه</label>
                                                            {{ user_information_editing_form.phone_number }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>انتخاب جنسیت</label>
                                                        {{ user_information_editing_form.gender_selection }}
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <h5 class="mb-1 mt-2 mt-sm-0"><i
                                                            class="feather icon-map-pin mr-25"></i>نشانی</h5>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label>آدرس</label>
                                                            {{ user_information_editing_form.location_first }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label>کد پستی</label>
                                                            {{ user_information_editing_form.postal_code }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-end mt-1">
                                                    <button type="button"
                                                            class="btn btn-primary glow mb-1 mb-sm-0 mr-0 mr-sm-1"
                                                            id="Test">
                                                        ذخیره تغییرات
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning">تنظیم مجدد
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        <!-- users edit Info form ends -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <!-- users edit ends -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
<!-- END: Content-->


<!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
{% block page_vendor_js_edit_user %}
    <script src="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/select/select2.full.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/validation/jqBootstrapValidation.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.date.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
<!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->


<!-- BEGIN: Page JS-->
{% block page_js_edit_user %}
    <script src="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/js/scripts/pages/app-user.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'AdminPanel/app-assets/js/scripts/navs/navs.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
<!-- END: Page JS-->
```

Answer (score 0):

there is some approaches to your question, first I suggest [ModelFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). you could add a modelformset to another form so reduce the confliction. another way is have only one submit button for all forms in the same page. or control the submission of each form using JS, there is a `submit()` function available and it could be mixed with `serialize()` function too. e.g:

```
$("#form1_sub_btn").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: form1.serialize

        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I think you did not understand. I do not need duplicate forms on one page. There are two separate forms with separate fields, the only problem is when validating and calling them, instead of

Comment: ` I do not need duplicate forms on one page`! using ModelFormSet not necessarily is to have duplicate or more of a same Form in the page. its for having one or more form for a model attached to a single form of another model, so you could attach only one form!. it seems you couldn't get the trick.